# How can I add a progress bar to Managed File upload?

Tags: 7, ajax, files

How can I add a progress bar to my Managed File form field? Here's my field code:

```
    $form['file'] = array(
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#title' => t('Logo image'),
  '#description' => t('Replace/upload a new logo for this sponsor.'),
  '#upload_location' => 'public://',
  '#upload_validators' => array(
    'file_validate_extensions' => array('gif png jpg jpeg'),
  ),      
);
```

I have searched for a while now, and the closest info I could find was [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23685/how-do-i-create-a-progress-bar) but I can't quite figure out how I can add the AJAX to make this happen. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

managed_file fapi elements are already progress bar capable by default.

[**managed_file**](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#managed_file)

> **Description**: Provides a complete ajax/progress aware widget for
>   uploading a file and saving it to the {file_managed} table.
>
> By default a simple upload button is provided for choosing the file to
>   upload. Once a file has been chosen it can be explicitly uploaded via
>   the "Upload" button. The upload is via AJAX and a progress meter is
>   displayed.
>   ....
>
> **Non-standard form element properties**:
>
> `#progress_indicator`: options are 'none', 'bar', and 'throbber', default is 'throbber'.
>   `#progress_message`: (string) Progress message to display along with progress meter while a file is being uploaded. Defaults to NULL.

It may be possible that your server doesn't support file progress, in which case you should check and verify if the server settings are correct.

More info:

- https://drupal.org/node/793262
- https://drupal.org/node/793264
- https://drupal.org/node/654732

Comment: awesome answer, has all the useful info.

Comment: @David - I got the bar to show up but it seems to freeze at the beginning (showing just a bit of blue) instead of "filling in" as the file uploads... any ideas why it would do that? I'm uploading a 100MB file but the bar has been frozen in same "initial" spot for almost 20 minutes, yet the browser is still indicating the upload is progressing

Comment: Looks like it's my server problem. I'm looking into the more info links at the end of your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @David, I installed the PECL Uploadprogress (the second link in your answer) and that solved the issue, now it works like a charm!