# Managed_file form does not show #default_value

Tags: files

I am using managed_file in Drupal 7 for my custom module. Other than the form api and managed_file, I'm using my own custom tables for this module.

This will eventually be used on shared hosting via Dreamhost, so the requirements of using PECL extensions are probably not available at [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/78842/how-can-i-add-a-progress-bar-to-managed-file-upload) suggests.

The behavior I want is when the file is uploaded by clicking the "upload" button, I at least want the image file to be a link that appears to indicate to the user that the file is uploaded. When I left the default #progress_indicator in place, the AJAX indicates it never uploads. However, this is false as I can see the file in managed_file table in the db.

I've looked through several searches for this and this is the form that I've come up and I cannot see what I'm doing wrong.

$item is the result of a database call of the previous object. Its genesis was derived from a [post jaypan provided](http://www.drupal.org/node/2069383).

```
$form['#item'] = $item;

dpm($item); => //every attribute to the sponsor object in the database.

$uri = isset($item->logoFileID) ? fetch_name('file_managed', 'uri', 'fid', $item->logoFileID) : '';

$uri = isset($item->logoFileID) ? fetch_name('file_managed', 'uri', 'fid', $item->logoFileID) : '';
dpm($uri); => 'public://logos/myfile.gif' //to show valid return of $uri
dpm($item-logoFileID); => 'public://logos/myfile.gif'

  $form['logoFileID'] = array(
    '#title' => 'file key',
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#default_value' => $item->logoFileID,
    );
 $form['logo_fid'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' => t('Logo'),
    '#description' => t('Upload a file, allowed extensions: jpg, jpeg, png, gif'),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://logos/',
    '#progress_indicator' => 'none',
    '#default_value' => $file->uri,
    );
```

As I said, managed_file does save the file and returns an fid that I save with the sponsor record. The behavior I have gotten in this module is that the filename was showing in this part of a form, that when clicked in Drupal shows a popup modal of the image. My question is how do I get this back link back to appear in the form to show the user it has been uploaded?, thx sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of a managed file field is a file ID, rather than its URI.

Assuming `$file` in your code is a file object, change the element array to:

```
$form['logo_fid'] = array(
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#title' => t('Logo'),
  '#description' => t('Upload a file, allowed extensions: jpg, jpeg, png, gif'),
  '#upload_location' => 'public://logos/',
  '#progress_indicator' => 'none',
  '#default_value' => $file->fid,
);
```

Comment: Yes, you are certainly right!