# I want to show a progress bar during form is submitted and processed until submission is created

Tags: forms

I am using Form API to create a form on a page and I ask user to submit CSV File which is then process in _submit function for that form. Kindly suggest me a way to add progress bar with Drupal's way. I tried this actually but did not work.

```
function userop_form_users($form_state) {

  $form['file'] = array(
    '#type' => 'file',
    '#title' => t("Upload CSV file containing information."),
    '#description' => t('<a href="#">Download sample file</a>.<br>Upload a file, allowed extensions: csv'),
    '#ajax' => array(
        'progress' => array('type' => 'bar', 'message' => t('TestMessage'),'interval' => '1500'),
     ),
    );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  );

  $form['#cache'] = FALSE;
  return $form;
}
```

Comment: Related: [How do I create a progress bar?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23685/how-do-i-create-a-progress-bar)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I add a progress bar to Managed File upload?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/78842/how-can-i-add-a-progress-bar-to-managed-file-upload)

Comment: What if I need to display a progress bar like we see after cancelling/deleting users? I don't want to show upload progress, just a bar showing to wait for a while.

Comment: What is the point of a 'progress bar' if you don't want to show the progress of the upload?!?

Comment: Like, it is to let user know that processing it taking place so be patient.

Comment: Maybe just use the throbber progress_indicator then as that does not show the progress of the download.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use the [managed_file](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#managed_file) field type and set the `#progress_indicator` property to 'bar'.

More details are given in this [Drupal Answers answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/78843/11306)...